# Add space between plots for the plotmatrix function

Tags: matlab

Is there a way to add some space between the plots for the `plotmatrix` function? (I would like to label every `x` and `y` axis)

Comment: If each axis get's a different label, are you sure you want `plotmatrix` and not `subplot`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using a specific output argument in the call to `plotmatrix`. You can then retrieve the position of each individual axes and modify it (making it smaller).

Example:

```
clc
clear

rng default
X = randn(50,3);
Y = reshape(1:150,50,3);

%// Use this output argument
[~,AX,~,~,~] = plotmatrix(X,Y);

%// Fetch all the positions and alter them (make axes smaller)
AllPos = get(AX(:),'Position');

AllPos = vertcat(AllPos{:});

NewPos = [AllPos(:,1)+.05 AllPos(:,2)+.05 AllPos(:,3)-.1 AllPos(:,4)-.1]

%// Update the plot
for k = 1:numel(AX)
    axes(AX(k))

    set(AX(k),'Position',NewPos(k,:))

    xlabel(sprintf('Axes %i',k))

end
```

Outputs the following:

[image]

In contrast to the original plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again for your help, I really appriciate it.

Comment: Great you're very welcome! Your questions are very interesting :)